# Material UI Table size param missing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to get a standard [Material UI Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#dense-table) to be smaller, or how the Material UI team calls it *dense table*. Basically, I want to reduce the distance between all the lines.

As suggested within the Table description, there is a `size` param that allows to dense up all rows. The suggestion is this:

```
<Table size="small">
   // more stuff here
</Table>
```

This though does not work. I get errors that this param does not exist within the `Table` tag. I use NPM to load all I need from Material UI and these are my versions in use:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "4.0.0",
  "@material-ui/icons": "4.0.0",
  "@types/jquery": "3.3.29",
  "@types/material-ui": "0.21.6",
  "@types/react": "16.8.7",
  "@types/react-dom": "16.8.2",
  "jquery": "3.3.1",
  "react": "16.8.4",
  "react-dom": "16.8.4",
  "react-hot-loader": "4.8.0",
  "tslib": "1.9.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
  "typescript": "3.4.5"
}
```

Is the size param really missing or is there already a suggested method for densing the table rows?

Comment: The size param should be there, have you tried clearing and re-installing your node_modules?

Comment: Why do you have `"@types/material-ui": "0.21.6"` in your dependencies? I'm pretty sure this will pull in incorrect type information.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Absolutely! Must have been a development leftover. Thanks for pointing that out. Removed it now.

Comment: @JoshWooding This did do the trick. Isn't it enough to execute `yarn` in the root folder after having made changes in the `package.json`? Is it always necessary to re-delete `node_modules`? Sounds a bit like a bug his workaround.

Comment: @Socrates `yarn` might have done it but I always like to make sure nothing weird happens and starting from a clean slate is an easy way to do that vs using `yarn` or `yarn --force` where it's not easy to see if everything behaved itself.